# npx react-native run-android info Starting JS server

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native application and I want to run it but there is some issue on that. when ever I runt he command  `npx react-native run-android` it stuck on `info Starting JS server...` . I have restart my system. try these command `yarn android`  `npm run android` and `npx run-android`. but none is working.